# How to Compare two Columns of Data to Ensure None of the Data Matches

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I am performing a comparison to ensure account numbers in df1 do not bleed over into other account numbers in df2

My intention is to identify and output the row coordinates and values in each df that contain any 'unwanted' matching account numbers

df1 & df2 have a single column that contains account numbers as follows:

`df1`
`Account Number`
`1234`
`5678`
`9101`
`1121`

`df2`
`Account Number`
`3141`
`5161`
`7181`
`9202`
`1222`
`1234`

The amount of rows in df2 are different than df1, and there is one matching value of 1234 in both dataframes. Considering each row count starts at zero, my desired output would be as follows:

`df1 Row 0 = df2 Row 5 as 1234`

I am new to pandas, so please do forgive my terminology, and methods to accomplish this. If there is a better more awesome way to do it, I would love to hear and implement it.

I did research and i think there might be a way to use merge or isin methods?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: If anybody who reads this post would like to see my working code using the accepted solution with it converted to read CSV's, I will post it for you upon request =)

Comment: sorry about the code indents, I tried to add four spaces before each indented line u gh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make sense to use `account number` as an index in the resulting `DataFrame` and store row numbers in columns. The simplest solution would be to check every pair of indexes in `df1` and `df2` and store the row numbers in `df3`, it would have O(n^2) complexity.

**Edit:** It looks like, you can increase performance by filtering `df1` and `df2` using `.isin`, although I only tested it with mock data. It is still O(n^2), but now n is the number of matching accounts, not total number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'account': [1234, 5678, 9101, 1121]}
d2 = {'account': [3141, 5161, 7181, 9202, 1222, 1234]}
d3 = {'r1': [], 'r2': []}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = d3)

match1 = df1.account.isin(df2.account.values)
match2 = df2.account.isin(df1.account.values)
for r1 in df1[match1].index:
    for r2 in df2[match2].index:
        if df1.account[r1] == df2.account[r2]:
            idx = df1.account[r1]
            row = {'r1': r1, 'r2': r2}
            df3.loc[idx] = row
```

**Edit 2:** I could get even better performance with this version, and it is simpler:

```
match1 = df1.account.isin(df2.account.values)

for r1 in df1[match1].index:
    idx = df1.account[r1]
    r2 = df2[df2.account == idx].index[0]
    row = {'r1': r1, 'r2': r2}
    df3.loc[idx] = row
```

**Edit 3:** If account numbers are not unique in `df1` and `df2` it won't be possible to use `account number` as index:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
match1 = df1.account.isin(df2.account.values)

for r1 in df1[match1].index:
    idx = df1.account[r1]
    for r2 in df2[df2.account == idx].index:
        row = {'account': idx, 'r1': r1, 'r2': r2}
        df3 = df3.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi Nikita, I'm in the process of testing out yer code now, but just so ya know the account numbers live in x2 two different csv's so I have them loaded up as DataFrames in df1 and df2, but i'll test out your proof of concept code, and let you know how it works out for me =) Thank you so much for your efforts too! =P

Comment: Okay Awesome! your proof of concept code is working! I'm going to now attempt to redirect it to my CSV's =)

Comment: Excellent! I got it operational with my CSV's and it works perfect! Excellent first contribution on Stackoverflow, you are on  your way to greatness =P

Comment: FYI: for larger data, this might not be the solution, because I loaded up a csv with 48k rows, and started it about 2 minutes ago, and its still chugging away, so I think a faster solution will be needed =) -- for now i'm going to retract this as an excepted solution, so others may also have a chance to chime in with their thoughts =)

Comment: I managed to speed up the solution by filtering `df1` and `df2` with `.isin()`  function, it runs much faster on random data.

Comment: Sweet! I will try integrating that now and let ya know how it goes =D

Comment: man you are soooo close! the idx value is correct, as I can find matching values for it in both CSV files, but the reference to which row it is, is incorrect. Here is the code I have in place:

Comment: It might be because account numbers repeat in CSV files. If this is the case, you could use `.append(row, ignore_index=True)` instead of setting `.loc[idx] = row`, with `row = {'account': idx, 'r1': r1, 'r2': r2}`

Comment: I just checked for duplicate account numbers in each CSV, and does not seem to be there, i'll play with this new code ya just posted =)

Comment: Got it working perfectly with the second solution, just incremented the index values by two on each one, and it picks up the exact rows, and it also picks up on duplicates! We are good to go!! Thank ya Sir!!! =) =) =)

Comment: and the time it takes for it to process is darn near instant! =)

Answer (score 2):

You could merge on the column, then use the output to lookup problem rows in the original datasets

```py
target_col = 'Account Number'
matching_account_nos = pd.merge(df1[[target_col]], df2[[target_col]], on='Account Number'), how='inner').values

# now use this to look up the rows in the original dataframes
problem_rows_df1 = df1[df1[target_col].isin(matching_account_nos)]
problem_rows_df2 = df2[df2[target_col].isin(matching_account_nos)]
```

The merge will return a dataframe with rows where 'Account Number' is equal. The `.values` will turn this into a numpy array which you could use to look up which rows in the original dataframe you need?

Comment: Okay Awesome! Thank you so much, I will integrate this into my code as soon as I can, and get back to you with the results as soon as I have them! =) =) =)

Comment: Okay so when I ran this code, it was throwing compiler errors, and I determined another opening parenthesis was needed. So I placed it after 'pd.merge(df1(' and the compiler is no longer throwing errors, but when I run it it gives a Type Error of 'DataFrame' object is not callable? Am I missing something? =)

Comment: Although I accepted the other answer as my solution, I would love to troubleshoot through yer method too, and implement it as a proof of concept, so I can later test performance wise which solution is more optimal when it comes to running this against millions of rows. All of your time and efforts are far beyond appreciated too! =) =P

Comment: I'm getting closer to getting your solution working, and already tested it on 48k rows, and the results are instant. It just appearing in scientific notation, which is weird, but it is identifying matches =)